# mysqli_stmt_fetch(). Entries exist, but nothing is printed

Tags: php

Am i doing something ridiculously stupid?
Everything works up until hello you(2)

while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($selectCust)) won't execute.
I went through everything step by step and the entries appear in the database. 
The if statement executes properly if the entry is original.

I did this entire form in mysql originally and it worked fine. 
I just can't get the fetch to work with prepared statements, so I'm sure it isn't 
a logic error.

```
Creating prepared statements and binding params
$insertCust = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, 
"INSERT INTO `mp434`.`CUSTOMERS` (
`CUST_ID`,
`NAME` ,
`EMAIL` ,
`PASSWORD` ,
`ADDRESS`
)
VALUES (
?, ?, ?, ?, ?
)");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insertCust, 'sssss', $null, $name, $email, $password, $address);

$selectCust = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, 
"SELECT *
FROM `CUSTOMERS`
WHERE `NAME` LIKE ?
AND `EMAIL` LIKE ?
AND `PASSWORD` LIKE ?
AND `ADDRESS` LIKE ?");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($selectCust, 'ssss', $name, $email, $password, $address);


//Find num Rows to see if cust is preexisting
mysqli_stmt_execute($selectCust);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($selectCust);
$numRows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($selectCust);
mysqli_stmt_close($selectCust);

//if preExisting gives Cust ID
//if not fetches custId 

if ($numRows == 0)
{
mysqli_stmt_execute($insertCust);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($insertCust);
$custID = mysqli_stmt_insert_id($insertCust);
mysqli_stmt_close($insertCust);
}
else
{
print "hello1";
mysqli_stmt_execute($selectCust);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($selectCust, $a,$b,$c,$d,$e);
print "hello You2";
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($selectCust))
    {
        print "hello You3";
        print "results are: $custID $b $c $d $e <br>";
    }

mysqli_stmt_close($selectCust);
}
echo $custID;
echo $numRows;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the return value of `mysqli_stmt_execute` to see if there was an error executing the query.

However I think problem is that you've already run this query and haven't bound the parameters since then before running it again.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I re-prepared and rebound and it worked perfectly. Thank you, I've never used mySqli before.